# Best places to put protective clear stickers

Tags: paint, preventative-maintenance

I want to protect the new paint of my bicycle, so I'm thinking of putting some transparent stickers to the most prone to scratch areas of the frame.
But what are the most prone to scratch areas?

Comment: Depending on your bike, it might be quite hard to damage the finish (e.g. if your bike is actually powdercoated rather than painted).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few places you may want to consider

- Right chain stay where the chain knocks against it.
- Bottom of the down tube where rocks might get flung from your tires.
- Around the headtube, check if there's any place where the gear and brake cables contact the frame when turning the bars. Rubbing cable mat seem insignificant but can easily wear away paint with enough time.

Comment: Sides of the front fork if it is ever locked to  a bike rack